# WinForms Flexible Grid and Tiles

Tags: c#, winforms

I'd greatly appreciate some help with the following scenario.

I have a WinForms app which contains a 4x4 grid of squares. My overall aim is to be able to select an "item" from a "toolbox" within the application and drag it onto a square in the grid. I also want to be able to resize the "item" to fill a number of adjacent squares.

The following link shows an image of my desired outcome.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bw0lw24F4HvoXzZQYzBSNzZMV0E/edit?usp=sharing

I envisage having the following classes:

Tile - this class represents a single tile. Its default functionality would render a blank, empty tile but derived classes would override this functionality.

TileGrid - this is a UserControl which represents the 4x4 grid. It would contain an array of empty Tile classes. When the user wants to add a custom Tile to the grid, the target element in the 2D array would be replaced with the custom Tile.

What I'm stuck with is how to get a tile to span multiple grid spaces. For example, Item1, Item5 and Item-n from the image. Using my ideas from above, I can't see how I could mould the TileGrid array to fit this type of functionality.

I'd be grateful for any pointers or assistance.

If my question isn't perfectly clear, I apologise in advance.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: That is a TableLayoutPanel.

Comment: You must separate the __data structure__, the way to __display__ and the way the user will __interact__. I suggest to consider a `DataGridview`, which can easily cover both points 2 and 3. You will still need a data structure to get the functionality you want.

Comment: Thanks for both your comments. It looks like a TableLayoutPanel could be the closest fit with probably the most simple implementation.